# jQuery remote validate not working with django url

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-validate

when i submit form, adno field (number) not validate excluding empty

my template.html

```
<input name="adno" id="id_adno" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="" required>
```

jquery validate remote

```
        adno: {
          remote: {
            url: "{% url 'is_adno_valid' %}",
            type: "post",
            data: {
              field_value: function () {
                return $("#id_adno").val();
              },
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
            }
          }
        },
```

views.py and urls.py

```
def is_adno_valid(request):
    adno = int(request.POST.get('adno'))
    return JsonResponse({'status':adno==1111})

urls.py

path('is_adno_valid',views.is_adno_valid, name='is_adno_valid'),
```

when i try to submit form with adno field as empty, red border of error showing. but whe enter any number it not showing error. ie, remote not working

Comment: Review the documentation for the `remote` method.  You are supposed to return a *"JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements"*.  Instead, you are returning a boolean `true`.  I am also not sure about the use of `return`.  What is the Python equivalent of `echo`?  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: Also, you're expected to post some troubleshooting results here.  Like inspecting your console for server responses, errors, etc.